# Create a Sierpinksi Triangle using 0L-System with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, fractals

I need to create a Sierpinksi Triangle using 0L-System with Python.
See here: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa8yz.png)
I'm stuck here, I can't complete the triangle.

My code:

```
from turtle import *


def sierpinksi(size: int, n: int):
    if n == 0:        
        for i in range(0, 3):
            forward(size)
    else:

        sierpinksi(size//2, n-1) #F
        right(120)               #-

        sierpinksi(size//2, n-1) #G
        left(120)                #+
        sierpinksi(size//2, n-1) #F
        left(120)                #+
        sierpinksi(size//2, n-1) #G
        right(120)               #-
        sierpinksi(size//2, n-1) #F


sierpinksi(100, 2)
done()
```

My result: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCHMg.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can put a band-aid on your code by finishing the triangle after the fact and using floating division instead of integer division:

```
from turtle import *

ANGLE = 120

def sierpinksi(size, n):

    def sierpinksi_recursive(size, n):
        if n == 0:
            for _ in range(3):
                forward(size)
        else:
            sierpinksi_recursive(size/2, n-1)  # F
            right(ANGLE)                       # -
            sierpinksi_recursive(size/2, n-1)  # G
            left(ANGLE)                        # +
            sierpinksi_recursive(size/2, n-1)  # F
            left(ANGLE)                        # +
            sierpinksi_recursive(size/2, n-1)  # G
            right(ANGLE)                       # -
            sierpinksi_recursive(size/2, n-1)  # F

    sierpinksi_recursive(size, n)

    for _ in range(2):
        right(ANGLE)
        forward(size * 3)

speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience
sierpinksi(100, 3)
done()
```

But I believe the real problem is you've not embraced the spirit of the L-system, ignoring the starting production 'F-G-G' and not implementing the production rules.  Your code does a lot of redundant drawing which makes it relatively slow.  If instead we implement the L-system head on, we address all the issues:

```
from turtle import *

ANGLE = 120

RULES = {
    'F': 'F-G+F+G-F',
    'G': 'GG',
    '+': '+',
    '-': '-',
}

def sierpinksi(string, size, n):
    if n:
        string = ''.join(RULES[c] for c in string)
        sierpinksi(string, size/2, n-1)
    else:
        for c in string:
            if c in 'FG':
                forward(size)
            elif c == '+':
                left(ANGLE)
            elif c == '-':
                right(ANGLE)

speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience
sierpinksi('F-G-G', 300, 3)
done()
```